# Google Authenticator - generate new set of emergency codes

Tags: ssh, security, verification, google-authenticator, password

I use Google Authenticator on my SSH servers with Andoid app for generating codes.

After I run `$ google-authenticator` application create set of emergyncy keys:

```
https://www.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/user@machine%3Fsecret%ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
Your new secret key is: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
Your verification code is 123456
Your emergency scratch codes are:
  12345678
  90123456
  78901234
  56789012
  34567890
```

What can I do if used all 5 codes? How can I generate new set? If I run `$ google-authenticator` it will generate new key `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP` and Android app stop working until I setup new key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.google_authenticator in your home directory should list the rescue codes. Just add new ones.